# Congruences mod 3

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We have the following congruences:

$a^2+2dbc \equiv 0 \mod 3$

$b^2+2ac \equiv 0 \mod 3$

$2ab+dc^2 \equiv 0 \mod 3$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d$ is a square free integer that is not divisible by $3$ and $d \not \equiv \pm 1 \mod 9$.

Deduce that $a \equiv c \equiv \pm 1 \mod 3$ and $b \equiv dc \mod 3$.

I don't get why these should be solutions. Moreover $a \equiv b \equiv c \equiv 0 \mod 3$ is a solution too.

Comment: are we caring about trivial solutions ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I don't have any restrictions on the solutions...

Comment: sure you do, d can't be 0,1,3,6, or 8 mod 9

Comment: Yeah but $a \equiv b \equiv c \equiv 0 \mod 3$ is a solution independent of $d$.

Comment: That's called a trivial solution. in math, we care more about the non-trivial.

Comment: I know that is a trivial solution, but without any restrictions on $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ I can say that what I'm asked to find are some of the solutions, but not all of them, since I have also the trivial ones.